# Uploading an image with Facebook Ads Management API

Tags: facebook, powershell

I am trying to upload an image to Facebooks ads management api in Powershell to use the image hash later when creating the actual ad.

```
$fileName = "adimage.jpg"
$fileContent = get-content $fileName
$fileContentBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($fileContent)
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes)

$parameters = @{
    access_token = "abc"
    bytes = $fileContentEncoded
}

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/act_12345678/adimages" -Method Post -ContentType "image/jpeg" -body $parameters
```

I always get:

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":1487242,
"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Image Resize Failed",
"error_user_msg":"Image Resize Failed:Could not get image size","fbtrace_id":"Bl\/fu39rM2W"}}
```

The API page for the adimages endpoint is:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image

We are basically looking for the equivalent of

```
curl -F "filename=@adimage.jpg" -F "access_token=abc" https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/act_12345678/adimages
```

I have also tried:

- using a png image
- using "bytes = (get-content adimage.jpg -Raw)"
- posting the image via the -infile parameter and adding the access token as a parameter instead of as a form field

  - the result of this (and also of some other variations) is that I get no error and a 200 response, but an empty content field and no file is uploaded either

The images in question are:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkx236uiiy1p54e/adimage.jpg?dl=0
and
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gf9on4w8ijbfwl8/adimage.png?dl=0

Upload via the Asset management GUI worked.

Any ideas?

Sandro

Update: it did indeed work like a charm with curl on a Mac. That makes it even more unlikely that it is about the images themselves

Comment: Could not get it to work. Using a VERY crude workaround, which uses CURL from a cygwin installation now. Please still post an answer, if you have something to contribute though. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using node.js to call the Graph API. I was trying to UTF-8 encode the file bytes and then base64 encode the result, but I got the same error.

When I drop the UTF-8 file encoding and used the raw bytes (still base64 encoded) it works fine for me.

So this fails with the same "Image Resize Failed" error:

```
fs.readFile(imagePath, 'UTF8', (err, fileData) => {
    let postData = {
        name: 'My Image',
        bytes: new Buffer(fileData).toString('base64')
    };    
    request.post(url, {form: postData}, (err, response, body) => ...
```

But this works (no UTF-8 encoding):

```
fs.readFile(imagePath, (err, fileData) => {
    let postData = {
        name: 'My Image',
        bytes: new Buffer(fileData).toString('base64')
    };
    request.post(url, {form: postData}, (err, response, body) => ...
```

Comment: Confirming that this is still the case. The API docs say 'utf8 as buffer64' but thet mean binary data as buffer64. If you are using request libraries with your images make sure to set `{ encoding: null }` or something equivalent.